# flask relative path edit

Tags: python, selenium, flask, http-status-code-404

i am working in python
i am parsing code from different webshops with selenium an print them to 1 overview page made with flask

```html
    webshopresultaten = resultatenlijstwebshop.get_attribute('outerHTML')#getting the HTML code from the by selenium recognized part of the suppliers website

    print("<h1>webshop resultaten</h1>" + webshopresultaten)
    liresultaten = "<h1>webshop resultaten</h1>" + webshopsresultaten  #adding a title to this list
    return render_template("interface.html", liresultaten=liresultaten) #using flask to show the HTML snippet from suppliers page on my page
```

so, the webshopresultaten variable gives me an snippet of the supplier website and i want to print it on an local hosted webpage with flask
everything works well, only problem is that in the HTML snippet of the suppliers website contains following

```html
href="ajaxElement/imgProtect_2y10WMa3vtEp7msffVjVRPy4Of44HBmRSGVcDrf7Z4A9JMEoGSZM8li.jpg"
```

how can i make this link refer to the domain name of the supplier so the picture becomes visible in my localhosted page

Comment: I can't follow the question at all.

Comment: hmm, how to make myself clear, .... do you know how selenium works?

Comment: Vaguely, but I don't see how that's relevant. `href="ajaxElement/imgProtect_2y10WMa3vtEp7msffVjVRPy4Of44HBmRSGVcDrf7Z4A9JMEoGSZM8li.jpg"` is hard-coded so where does Flask come into this?

Comment: i added some comments to my code snippet above, to explain further, i use selenium to get parts of my suppliers webshop. by the .get_attribute() i receive the HTML code direct from the supplier, final, i use flask to print this on a self made page, there is where the problem starts, my supplier hard coded the picture link in his website without domain

Comment: Sure, but it's still nothing to do with flask. You're asking about string concatenation, no? My best guess is that you're missing some domain name, but I still don't follow

Comment: the clue of my question is: how to add the suppliers domain name in the middle of that html string retrieved from supplier